# How to get the object of Iframe at clientside(javascript) which placed inside Table in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have iframe inside the column of `<asp:table>`. I want to get the object of an iframe in javascript. I tried like this in `<body>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeIframe()
    {
        var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        height -= document.getElementById('frame').offsetTop;
        height -= 20;         
        document.getElementById('frame').style.height = height + "px";
    };

    document.getElementById('frame').onload = resizeIframe;
    window.onresize = resizeIframe;
</script>
```

But I'm getting error like *"object expected or null"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document has probably not finished loading (so, `#frame` does not exist yet). To fix this, make sure that the frame already exists by adding the code after the frame (or at the end of the document):

```
<iframe .../> ...
<script>
document.getElementById('frame').onload = resizeIframe;
window.onresize = resizeIframe;
</script>
```